# Possible hide the link view on the bottom left corner?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to hide the link view on the bottom left corner.
it makes the "Kampung Marketer" look weird. huh.
How should I do it? What method should be done?

**HTML Code**, I'm using `<a href>` for open the folder.

```
<ul class="nav">
        <li class="active">
          <div class="zf-folder">
            <div class="_tabFolder _itemPosition" style="height: 40px;border-bottom:1px groove; user-select: none;">
              <div class="_sideFolder"></div>
              <div class="_iconText" style="width: 215px">
                <div class="ellipsis">
                  <div class="_iconFolder">
                    <div class="_icon-col">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <a href="#mainFolder" data-toggle="tab" style="text-decoration: none;">All Audience [Main Folder]<span class="hyperspan" style="position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; left:0; top:0;"></span></a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
</ul>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

That is a browser feature when you hover an `<a>` element with its `href` attribute set, so there is no way to directly hide it. However, you could skip the `href` attribute or use any other element than `a`, and simply use JS to navigate to your target with `onclick="window.location.href = 'your_url_here';"`.